# Pictures in drawable folders do not work - why?

Tags: android

I created the corresponding drawable folders in android studio for the application, but the images in it did not work properly, with two different devices in terms of their resolution for two different results. The application only displays the image in only 1 folder and makes the layout skewed in 2 types of devices.
I have created small-normal-large layout files, they work fine, but when the same layout type (for example the same type of normal screen on both devices), the photos were in the wrong position when designing.

Screen 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9e1y.png)

Screen 2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjGNG.png)

Layout XML of both screens.

[Here are the layout XML of two screens above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4Fx6.png)

Comment: please include any images you have as part of your question here, as people don't want to click on off-site resources

Comment: please add you xml file

Comment: `Pictures ... do not work` ... ?! A picture is not supposed to **work** unless (in a certain meaning) it's an animated GIF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you manually assign margin left and margin top. please remove margin if given and make parent layout relative and image view make it `centerInParent="true"` also fixed the height and width on image view

To continue use ConstraintLayout you can try below

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: thank for your help, your way helps keep the layout centered automatically in relative layout, but I still want to find a solution when using constraint layouts for screens. You can suggest me other way.

Comment: @TinNguyen please check edited answer. i hope it helps you